# How to root Lenovo A1000 Smartphone?

Tags: rooting

I tried [Kingo Root](https://www.kingoapp.com/) and [Root Genius](http://rootgenius.com/) and some other software but finally failed to root this phone. My phone is Lenovo A1000.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We will need more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The Android version it is running.

Comment: For users who flagged this as "Unclear what you're asking": [assume Android 5.0](http://shopap.lenovo.com/in/en/smartphones/a-series/a1000/) if OP doesn't clarify since I don't think Lenovo pushed any update beyond that version.

Comment: I have Android 5.0 and i can't Root this Phone.

Answer (score 1):

To root a Lenovo A1000 smartphone (Android 5.0), go to [kingroot.net](http://kingroot.net/) and follow their directions to download, install, and run KingRoot.  I downloaded the Android .apk to my Linux laptop and copied it to the phone via adb, but I'm sure downloading directly to the phone (they provide a QR code) would also work.

By the way, add SuperSU to the list of ones that do not work on this phone.